# After publishing to Azure, External Component Has Thrown an Exception

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've deployed my [site](http://mfeweb.azurewebsites.net) to Azure and have received the above error with stack trace as follows:

```
Exception type: HttpCompileException
Exception message: External component has thrown an exception. at  
System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean    isPrecompiledApp) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax()   
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() at   
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() at   
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager   
appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory   
configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, 
PolicyLevel policyLevel,    Exception appDomainCreationException)
```

This is an ASP.NET MVC5 web application with AngularJS front end.  What must be modified to remedy this issue?

Comment: Can you have a peek in Kudo to see if you have any extra errors.  The link for your site should be (https://mfeweb.scm.azurewebsites.net)

Comment: I did.  Looks like my Web API project is at cause.  Am going to redeploy it as an Azure app service API.  Thanks for pointing out Kudu.

Comment: Not a problem, Kudu is that one magical thing that we all eventually figure out.  I was late to the game, but it sure helps!  (Might check that your deploy included ALL of the DLL's needed as well.  Had a deploy miss a few once.)